# Strange Syntax with Missing Particles

Tags: particles, syntax, particle-を, song-lyrics

In the FFX-2 song "[Morning Glow](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/KUON:_Memories_of_Waves_and_Light#Lyrics)," some of the lyrics seem to end abruptly with the を particle, and yet have the ending verbs that would come after it in front of the phrases.

One example is the first verse:

> 今も憶えているの
> あなた旅立つ日に見た夢を
> 涙つたうあなたの頬
> 手を伸ばすと 闇の中消えた

I currently understand the verse as: I still remember the dream I had on the day you left when I reached out for your tear-stained? cheek, and it vanished into the darkness.

It looks like 憶えているの should come after the を particle on the second line, especially since の being between a verb and pronoun, let alone the middle of a sentence, seems grammatically incorrect like in the fourth verse. Then maybe つたう (伝う) should come before 涙 like in a relative clause, and に should be between 頬 and 手 to connect the bottom two lines.

Comment: It's not specific to を. [Look up 倒置 on this site](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E5%80%92%E7%BD%AE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (あなた旅立つ日に見た)夢を coming after 今も憶えているの is a somewhat common grammatical technique where some part of the sentence (subject, or object, etc) will be placed after the verb (with its corresponding particle) for emphasis or effect.

The first two lines, if put into a more "standard" form would read:

> あなた(が)旅立つ日に見た夢を今も憶えているの。
> (I) still remember the dream (I) had the day you left.

(As Chance explained, the の here is not a connector but a sentence-ending particle.)

However, it has been rearranged to essentially say something more like:

> 今も憶えているの
> あなた旅立つ日に見た夢を
> (I) still remember it,
> The dream (I) had the day you left.

Likewise, the third and fourth lines are basically (IMHO) separated by an implicit comma, because the speaker is essentially listing off the different things they remember from the dream:

> 涙つたうあなたの頬、
> 手を伸ばすと 闇の中消えた
> Your tear-stained cheeks,
> (I) reached out (my) hand, and (you) disappeared into the darkness

Comment: Think this sort of formatting is present anywhere else in the song?

Answer (score 1):

I think the lyrics mean this.

あなた(が)旅立つ日に(私が)見た夢を今も(私は)憶えているの。
(その内容は)涙(が)つたうあなたの頬(に)(私が)手を伸ばすと(あなたが)闇の中消えた。

の of 憶えているの does not mean "of". This の is often used when you tell a thing to someone.
If you don't use this の. It feels like you're just saying it to yourself.
の is normally used by female person. んだ has a similar meaning but it's used by anyone.